# How to select value from Oracle table having field name as default keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

We have Oracle table having default keyword(i.e in as field name) field name.Now i am querying table but unable to extract specific field data.

```
select a.filename,a.in from table a
```

Following error appears "invalid field name.

Comment: Can you provide some info about your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double quotes.

```
select a."IN" from table a
```

Comment: if IN is in small case in your table then you should try "in".

Comment: @imransatti i hope you are trying it with table name instead of "table" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default (**oracle reserved**) keywords as the name of the `columns` but yes it is not advisable to use it.

Anyway, If you want to use oracle reserved keywords then you must have to enclose them in the **double-quotes**.

Note that oracle is case insensitive in terms of its object names until and unless it is wrapped in the double-quotes. it means if you enclose any object name in double-quotes then you must have to use them anywhere in the entire DB as case sensitive manner.

So if your table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE ("IN" NUMBER);
```

Then you need to use `"IN"` wherever you want to refer the column but if your table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE ("in" NUMBER);
```

Then you need to use `"in"` wherever you want to refer the column. -- case sensitive names.

I hope it will clear all your doubts.

Cheers!!